# Why are facets not displayed on pages?

Tags: views, entities, search, 9

I have two entities: **Entity Product** and **Entity Product Category**. **Entity Product** has an entity reference field on the **Entity Product Category**.

##### Goal:

Display categories and their number on the right by facets.

##### What I did:

1. I created the **Product Category** view mode and selected it in **Entity Product**, where I disabled all the fields because I don’t need to display them, because I will display the facets:

[image]

2. Added the necessary fields to the previously created index and once again indexed the **Entity Product**:

[image]

3. Created view Categories results facets which will be used as Facet source. And in **Show:Rendered entity | Settings** in settings selected view mode **Product Category**:

[image]

4. Added a facet:

[image]

5. I chose **Categories results facets** view as Facet source:

[image]

6. Configured the facets:

[image]
[image]

8. Added the **Categories results facets** block to the Block layout:

[image]

But the facets are not displayed on any page.

Comment: One of the selected option is *Hide facet when facet source isn't rendered*. The view used as source for that facet isn't rendered when viewing the *Entity Product* entities.

Comment: @apaderno I tried unchecking this option but it didn't help. Perhaps the reason is different.